# Bundle Install Fail- Rails Tutorial

Tags: rubygems, installation, bundle, annotate

```
bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'annotate-models (= 1.0.4) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

But clearly its in my gemfile, isn't it?

source 'http://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '0.1.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
gem 'annotate'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.1'
  gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
end
```

I added gem 'annotate' and attempted what was recommended elsewhere on stack with no success. Any idea why it can't find the gem at the source? How could I manually override this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because a gem named "annotate-models" does not exist on rubygems.org.

Did you mean to use [annotate](https://rubygems.org/gems/annotate) or maybe [annotated_models](https://rubygems.org/gems/annotated_models) instead?  Neither one of them has a version 1.0.4 published, so I'm not sure what gem you're looking for.

Comment: The rails tutorial calls for annotate_models, but i reinstalled everything and haven't skipped ahead to that part yet so I'll cross that bridge when I come to it, hopefully it won't be a problem.